# Is there a Fish Function I can make to eliminate leading "$"/"#" from commands copied from sites?

Tags: function, fish

Sometimes when I'm copying and pasting a command from a site, I accidently copy the leading "$" or "#" by accident.  Is there a Fish Function I could make that would check if one of those is included in a command and automatically remove it before running it?

For example, if I copy and paste `$ sudo apt install foo bar poo`, I will get the error: `Commands may not contain variables. In fish, please use 'eval $'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
function '$'; eval $argv; end
```

Then

```
myprompt$ $ echo hello world
hello world
```